# XCode 8.1 - closure auto completion issue

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, closures

I have issue in auto-completing a closure:

My function prototype:

```
fileprivate func perform(on proto: MyType1, _ action: MyType2, _  completion: @escaping (_ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
// do my stuff
}
```

When I type the above function, XCode suggests:
[image: Ready to press Return for auto-completion]

At this point, I am supposed to press `Return` in order to get auto-completed. Actually when I press `Return`, XCode does not auto-complete for me (picture shown below):
[image]

Do you have any ideas to fix this? I am using XCode 8.1 (8B62).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a solution? It's annoying.

Comment: Not yet. I just figured out that this error just happens in some cases, sometimes only. This must be a bug of Xcode!